# Memcached memory consumption?

Tags: memcached, memcache

Server info:
cPanel / 4GB

The conf file as below:

```
#Memory a user
-m 128
# default port
-p 11211
# user to run daemon nobody/apache/www-data
-u nobody
# only listen locally
-l 127.0.0.1
```

Does it mean that it assign 128M to each account(domain)? Let's say if 10 sites are running, 128 * 10 = 1280M will be consumed for the server?

Please correct me if wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcached has no concept of "domains", "sites", "accounts", "users", or anything else of that nature.  It's just a big box that you put things in and take then out of.  In this case, you've specified that the box may be up to 128MB in size.

It is possible that cPanel may have some sort of "memcached per account" functionality; if that's the case, you'll want to consult cPanel support about the impact of their proprietary functionality on your system operation.